# how to show all the fields and a number count in one sql query

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

right now I have

```
select data.* from
complicated select with 100 joins
as data
```

and I want it to be

```
select data.*, count(*) as total from
complicated select with 100 joins
as data
```

but the second one is not working, its only returning one result with the total number in it.

What I want is return all the results(with all the fields) ,plus a total number as one field in every result.

result.field1=xx
result.field2=xx
.....
result.total = 1000000,

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 2 queries:

1) is Your query with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS data.* FROM
complicated select with 100 joins
as data;
```

2) is to take calculated found rows:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS count;
```

More detailed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

BONUS: If You're using Sequelise ORM You must know that You can use models and `findAndCount` method that shortens Your logic. please read [this article](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findandcountfindoptions-promiseobject)